# How to set a background image with Monotouch.Dialog

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

What is the best way to set a background image (below all controls) in `Monotouch.Dialog`?  I am using the `Elements` API of `Monotouch.Dialog`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main *trick* is to set the `TableView` background colour to `Clear` then setting the `ParentViewController.View` to your image, like:

```
class MyDialogViewController : DialogViewController {

    public MyDialogViewController (RootElement root) : base (root)
    {
    }

    public override void LoadView ()
    {
        base.LoadView ();
        TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        UIImage background = UIImage.FromFile ("background.png");
        ParentViewController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (background);
    }
}
```